# Shapebuilder tool wont let me change colour illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6

I'm trying to fill a colour using the shapebuilder tool however when I go to fill white it won't let me? I selected yellow and it filled but when I go to select white it jumps back to yellow very strange. Im clicking to fill to another colour but thats not working as well.

See images below for steps I take..

Select image and then select pathfinder tool. Fill has already been set to red.
[image]

[image]

Double click in fill box to change to white. But then when I click okay it still stays red?

[image]

Comment: You need to select color every time after you have activated shapebuilder tool. Because the selection overrides this value if any other tool is active.

Comment: I can replicate this problem unfortunately (or rather fortunately), but then again I don't have an old copy of CS6 to check. Perhaps what you are experiencing has been fixed in later versions? I'm using AI CC 2018  and the shape builder seems to work just fine when selecting a fill colour first.  Can you possibly show a screenshot/screen capture of the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the "simulate paper color" option??

Comment: @scott Im not sure what that is, how do I check if that has been activated?

Comment: If you don't know what it is, you aren't using it. It's not something which can be used by mistake (And really you don't ever want to use it).

Comment: Okay so I have tried changing colour while using the shapebuilder tool on a rectangle shape I just made and it works. So it must have something to do with the paths that I created for the images?? Maybe it has something to do with open paths because when I select certain parts of the artwork and recolour them it seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

I can't really replicate this problem, so the following is basically a guess.

Try this:

Double click on the Shape Builder tool, and check the options - make sure you have selected choose pick colors from "color swatches"

[image]

CS6 Dialog...

[image]

Comment: FYI.. I can't replicated the issue either, and using CS6

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Scott

Comment: Hi thanks for this my dialogue box is already set to these settings. I have figured out the order in which I do it for it to work would be.. choose swatch colour> make selection > click on shapebuilder tool > colour shape. But then it seems like such a lengthy process if I change my mind and want a different colour. I still don't understand why it won't let me change the colour while I am using the shapebuilder tool seems like a glitch.